# Does the ol Layer 'visible' property affect if a source is retrieved via url?

Tags: openlayers, vue.js

I'm using openlayers 6 to try and display rail networks interactively on a map. This map lives in a vue application, and I want to load all required resources (json formatted vectors) from their respective urls so that all the layers are in memory once the user loads the page. These vectors live in arcgis, and an example request for the 'BNSF' rail network looks like this:

```js
return new VectorLayer({
          source: new VectorSource({
            format: new GeoJSON(),
            url:
              'https://services.arcgis.com/WwCp9CWUBJDXJO79/arcgis/rest/services/BNSF/FeatureServer/' +
              '0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&f=geojson'
          }),
          style: style,
          zIndex: 99
        })
```

In vue there are life cycle hooks for attaching actions for `mounted` which I'm using to build all the layers and attach it to my map. The information for building these layers, live inside the `layerOptions` below:

```js
mounted () {
      this.layerOptions.forEach(
        (option) => {
          // make the layer - based on identified option.url [and option.color]
          if (option.layerType === 'tile') {
            option.layer = this.makeTileLayer(option.url)
          } else {
            if (option.baseUrl) {
              option.layer = this.makeEsriVectorLayer(option.baseUrl, option.color)
            } else {
              option.layer = this.makeVectorLayer(option.url, option.color)
            }
          }
          // initial the layer as invisible - based on option.layer.setVisisble(false)
          option.layer.setVisible(false)
          // add the layer to the map - based on $refs.map.addLayer & option.layer
          if (this.$refs.map) {
            this.$refs.map.addLayer(option.layer)
          }
        }
      )
    }
```

The problem is that sources never load until the layer's `visible` property is set. Notice, how I set that property to false so that even though the layers are loaded and attached to the map they are invisible till the user toggles their visibility. However, that pattern fails since the layers don't even load unless the `visible` property is set.

Please, how can I overcome this so that my layers load appropriately and are kept in memory till the user sets their `visible` property through the toggle? I have a hunch that the `visible` property of a Layer determines whether the layer bothers to even fetch the resources from the map server. I hope this is not the case, but so far this is the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: You can use setOpacity instead of setVisible if you need resources to load.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I will try it out and see if I can implement some logic for matching the toggle action to opacity.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the awesome suggestion @Mike, it does the job!

I used this callback to flip the visibility of the layer through the `visible` property.

```js
toggleLayerVisibility (option) {
        if (option.visible !== this.layerOptions.find(layer => layer.label === option.label).layer.getVisible()) {
          this.layerOptions.find(layer => layer.label === option.label).layer.setVisible(option.visible)
        }
      },
```

Now, I use this for the same effect but through the `opacity` property. I set 0.8 as visible and 0 as not-visible.

```js
toggleLayerOpacity (option) {
        if (this.layerOptions.find(layer => layer.label === option.label).layer.getOpacity() === 0) {
          this.layerOptions.find(layer => layer.label === option.label).layer.setOpacity(0.8)
        } else {
          this.layerOptions.find(layer => layer.label === option.label).layer.setOpacity(0)
        }
      },
```

This works well to put specific layers in and out of view based on the layer's opacity. The code is not optimized, but it works by finding the layer with the matching label (from the `LayerOptions`) and then adorns a suitable value for the `opacity` based on the toggle state.

This workaround meets my needs.